# Is there a more elegant way to add nullable ints?

Tags: c#, nullable, null-coalescing-operator

I need to add numerous variables of type nullable int. I used the null coalescing operator to get it down to one variable per line, but I have a feeling there is a more concise way to do this, e.g. can't I chain these statements together somehow, I've seen that before in other code.

```
using System;

namespace TestNullInts
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int? sum1 = 1;
            int? sum2 = null;
            int? sum3 = 3;

            //int total = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
            //int total = sum1.Value + sum2.Value + sum3.Value;

            int total = 0;
            total = total + sum1 ?? total;
            total = total + sum2 ?? total;
            total = total + sum3 ?? total;

            Console.WriteLine(total);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with provided solutions is that sum of nulls becomes zero. There are situations where you want the sum all nulls to be null. e.g. int? added = null, updated = null, deleted = null; int? total = added + updated + deleted; // null i.e. nothing has been done.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
var nums = new int?[] {1, null, 3};
var total = nums.Sum();
```

This relies on the [`IEnumerable<Nullable<Int32>>`overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065.aspx)  of the [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345537.aspx) Method, which behaves as you would expect.

If you have a default-value that is not equal to zero, you can do:

```
var total = nums.Sum(i => i.GetValueOrDefault(myDefaultValue));
```

or the shorthand:

`var total = nums.Sum(i => i ?? myDefaultValue);`

Comment: Is your approach better (performance wise) than simply doing `int total = (sum1 ?? 0) + (sum2 ?? 0) + (sum3 ?? 0);`? I mean you are creating an array just to sum their values. Does it affect much? I just want to know, though I wrote exactly similar code first, and then came searching for it ;-)

Comment: If all are null in the array I would expect the total to be null. With this the total is 0.

Answer (score 30):

```
total += sum1.GetValueOrDefault();
```

etc.

Answer (score 17):

Just to answer the question most directly:

```
int total = (sum1 ?? 0) + (sum2 ?? 0) + (sum3 ?? 0);
```

This way the statements are "chained" together as asked using a +

Comment: plus one for the brackets :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Nullable<int>> numbers = new List<Nullable<int>>();
numbers.Add(sum1);
numbers.Add(sum2);
numbers.Add(sum3);

int total = 0;
numbers.ForEach(n => total += n ?? 0);
```

this way you can have as many values as you want.

Answer (score 1):

How to about helper method -

```
static int Sum(params int?[] values)
{
  int total = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
     total += values[i] ?? 0;
  }
  return total;
}
```

IMO, not very elegant but at least add as many numbers as you want in a one go.

```
total = Helper.Sum(sum1, sum2, sum3, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
total += sum1 ?? 0;
total += sum2 ?? 0;
total += sum3 ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just substituting `(sumX ?? 0)` for `sumX` in the corresponding non-nullable expression?

```
using System; 

namespace TestNullInts 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            int? sum1 = 1; 
            int? sum2 = null; 
            int? sum3 = 3; 

            int total = 0; 
            total += (sum1 ?? 0) + (sum2 ?? 0) + (sum3 ?? 0); 

            Console.WriteLine(total); 
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest, most elegant usage of LINQ:

```
var list = new List<Nullable<int>> { 1, 2, null, 3 };
var sum = list.Sum(s => s ?? 0);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

You need the coalesce AFAIK to make sure the result is not nullable.

Comment: Since the Linq `Sum` extensions skip `null` elements, you can also say `var sum = list.Sum().Value` or `var sum = list.Sum() ?? 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If all numbers in the array are null I would expect the total to be null.

```
// E.g. 
int? added = null, updated = null, deleted = null; 
...
int? total = added + updated + deleted; // null i.e. nothing has been done.
```

Test Cases

```
Sum(new int?[] { null, null}).Dump(); // null   
Sum(new int?[] { 1, null}).Dump();    // 1
Sum(new int?[] { null, 2}).Dump();    // 2
Sum(new int?[] { 1, 2}).Dump();       // 3
```

Sample Implementation

```
int? Sum(int?[] numbers)
{
    int? total = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        int? item = numbers[i];
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (total == null)
            {
                total = item;
            }
            else
            {
                total += item;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return total;
}
```