# Simple Linq expression Sum - Not returning null value for empty list

Tags: linq, sum

I am creating a simple test method for sum of list to render null when the list is not rendering any value

```
        [Fact]
        public void GetSum()
        {
            List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>();
            list.Add(new TestClass
            {
                Amount = null,
                Id = 1
            });
            list.Add(new TestClass
            {
                Amount = null,
                Id = 0
            });
            IQueryable<TestClass> classes = list.AsQueryable();
     
            var sum = classes.AsEnumerable().Where(i => i.Id > 1).Select(i => i.Amount).Sum();
            var sum1 = classes.AsEnumerable().Sum(i => i.Amount);
            Assert.NotNull(sum);
        }

        #endregion Impact Ratio
    }
    public class TestClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double? Amount { get; set; }

    }
```

sum and sum1 both render 0, I want them up to be null in case the list is not having any appropriate value. Am I missing anything out in this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep null when adding Nullable int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172458/keep-null-when-adding-nullable-int) . It is about `int?` but similar steps can be taken also for `double?` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

the `Sum()` function works as it does so you will have to use another function to achieve what you want. One possibility is the `Aggregate()` function which allows you to define how you want the summation to work.

For example this seems to achieve what you want:

```
[Fact]
public void GetSum()
{
    var classes = new[]
    {
        new TestClass {Amount = null, Id = 1},
        new TestClass {Amount = 1, Id = 0}
    };

    var sum1 = classes.Where(i => i.Id > 1)
                      .Select(i => i.Amount)
                      .Aggregate((double?)null, (a, b) => a.HasValue && b.HasValue ? a + b : a ?? b);
    var sum2 = classes.Select(i => i.Amount)
                      .Aggregate((double?)null, (a, b) => a.HasValue && b.HasValue ? a + b : a ?? b);
    Assert.Null(sum1);
    Assert.NotNull(sum2);
}
```

Note that this method only works when you have an `IEnumerable` - it does not work with `IQueryable`, but you convert your `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` in your own example so I guess that is ok...